# Real world (or not) application of those distances

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Can you please tell me if there are some application in the real world (like mathematical models for some dynamical system or other things) or just in other branches of mathematics (topology, graph theory...) of those distances? I was studying them in a general way, and I got this curiosity. Thank you!

The $p-$ distance:
$$d_p(x, y) = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{k = 1}^n |x_k - y_k|^p}$$

The $\infty-$distance:

$$D_{\infty}(x, y) = \max_i \{ |x_i - y_i| \}$$

Comment: The $p$-distance for $p=1$ is sometimes called taxi-cab metric, with various usages in geographic information system (GIS). For $p=2$, it is the classic Euclidean metric, whose importance and application is needless to state. Both these types of metrics (and even more, such as those defined on topological spaces like function spaces) are extensively used in measure theory, general topology and real analysis.